# how to sort datetime column in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

One of my date time format column in jqGrid is in following format:

1 November 2030, Fri 11:59pm.

How do I implement default sorting in ascending order in my below colModel?

```
      colModel: [
            { name: 'startDate', width: 30},            
        ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean under "One of my date time format column in jqGrid is in following format"? jqGrid has **input data** and it displays the data using formatter defined in the `colModel`. The input data for the column could be `"2030-11-01T23:59:00Z"` and the column definition `{ name: 'startDate', width: 30, formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d F Y, D g:i:s A" }, sorttype: "date" }`

Comment: I am sorry for confusion, what I meant was my colModel is simply as follows -> colModel: [ { name: 'startDate', width: 30}, ].
My input data for startDate was in this kind of format already -> 1 November 2030, Fri 11:59pm. Under this kind of scenario, how do I implement default sorting in ascending order?

Comment: It I correctly understand your problem, you want that **jqGrid sorts** the dates. Thus it has to compare the input data. It should be clear that `1 November 2030, Fri 11:59pm` isn't good for that. You should see on the input data not as texts, but as the data. jqGrid provides many [predefined formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter) inclusive `formatter: "date"` and `sorttype` and one can difine custom formatters and sort functions. The most easy way to solve your problem is to change the format of input data.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `formatter: "date"` in combination with uncomfortable format ` 1 November 2030, Fri 11:59pm`, but to add `formatoptions: { srcformat: "d F Y, D g:i:s A", newformat: "d F Y, D g:i:s A" }, sorttype: "date" }`. It the case jqGrid will parse the input data to convert there to `Date`. In any way, please include in all questions about jqGrid **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and **the fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: Hi, thanks, the version of jqGrid I am using is 4.4.1, I will try your alternative solution and see if it works. thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! Version 4.4.1 is 6 years old (!!!). The version is dead since a long time. 6 years means an eternity in web development. It you still don't use IE6 only then I'd strictly recommend to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.15.4 which is compatible to 4.4.1 (or 4.15.5, which I'll publish today or in the next days). See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) examples of usage free jqGrid.

Comment: hi Oleg, i tried your alternative solution and seems like something is wrong? input data of 1 November 2030, Fri 11:59pm is converted wrongly by 
jqGrid into NaN undefined NaN, undefined 12:NaN:NaN PM. and input data of 21 August 2018, Tue 8:00pm is converted wrongly by jqGrid into 1 August 2018, Tue 12:08:00 AM

Comment: this is the colModel i used: { name: 'startDate', width: 60, formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "d F Y, D g:i:s A", newformat: "d F Y, D g:i:s A" }, sorttype: "date" }

Comment: If you want to solve the problem you should provide the demo (in JSFiddle, for example), which reproduces the problem. Do you tried to change the format of input data to ISO format "2030-11-01T23:59:00Z" and to use `formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d F Y, D g:i A" }`?

Comment: Hi, below is the demo, hope to solve this, thanks http://jsfiddle.net/hfbdsL7j/

Comment: your demo uses jqGrid 4.6, which is too late and out of any support too. I recommend you replace it to "free jqGrid" 4.15.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your demo use `srcformat: "ISO8601Long"`, which means the format of inpuf data like `"2030-11-01T23:59:00Z"` but not `"1 November 2030, Fri 11:59pm"`, which you use.

jqGrid can safe parse the input date which contains numbers only. Parsing of inputs, which contains texts like `Fri` is not work. I suggest you to **change the format of input data**. Only if you really can't change the format of input data then you can fix the problem by usage `sorttype` defined as function

```js
{
    name: 'startDate', width: 60,
    sorttype: function (cellValue) {
        return moment(cellValue, "D MMMM YYYY, ddd h:mm a").format();
    }
}
```

the above code use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) to parse the dates and replace there to ISO 8601 date format. The ISO dates will be used by jqGrid instead of original dates during sorting.

Comment: However, how do i implement default sorting (ascending order) on this column upon the first loading of the jqGrid?

Comment: @weili: You should post **more information** about your grid. Which `datatype` you use? Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in versin <=4.7) and so on. For example if you use `datatype: "json"` *without* `loadonce: true` then **the server is responsible** for initial sorting. If you use `datatype: "local"`, then you can add `sortname: "startDate"`. If you use `datatype: "json", loadonce: true` and free jqGrid .... And so on

Comment: hi Oleg, thanks! I am using datatype: "local" and your solution works again. thanks for all your help :)